# C++: Exceptions from inside a constructor: Yes or No?

Tags: c++, exception

On the internet I have found advice such as:

- "**Don't throw an exception from inside a constructor!**"
  and
- "**If constructing the object, throw an exception from inside the constructor!!**"

They contradict, can both be correct?

Take, for example, a class which opens a file, reads the data and closes the file, all within the constructor.  It may encounter an error condition while opening or reading from the file.  How should this error be handled?

What advice should I follow?  Is throwing an exception from a constructor possible and is it good practice?

How should errors within constructors be handled if exceptions are not a good idea?

(I am using GCC C++14 on Linux)

Comment: The answer is "it depends". You do not want a constructor to fail. So: 1 do not write constructors which can fail, 2 I repeat: don't, 3 if a constructor does fail throw an exception, 4 any exception from a constructor should be fatal. This is my opinion (to be as helpful as possible for you personally). Now I will close vote the question for being opinionated, to be as helpful as possible to the goals of this community. You can get me to reopen-vote, by providing enough detail to allow a definite answer. (So "needs details" can be seen as secondy close vote reason.)

Comment: Exception was actually invented as the only mechanism to get into error state from the constructor. In any case there are al lot of disadvantages for throwing errors from constructor, and  most important - once you've done it you can no longer off exception by compiler option. Excretions on gives you not really binary from the performance point of view.  You can actually use approach with not-throwing constructor and std::error_code and factory method pattern instead of throwing exception directly from constructor. It gives you ability to use and avoid exceptions whenever you want it or not.

Comment: If the constructor could leave the class in an invalid state (because of errors during construction) then the best thing to do is to throw an exception.

Comment: As you want to read data from a file, I would recommend you to write a `init`-method besides the constructor. Then you don't have trouble with exceptions whilst constructing an object.

Comment: can you give references for the advices you found? "Don't throw an exception from inside a constructor!" in this generality is a really poor advice

Comment: Maybe you switched constructor with destructor? Never throw in a destructor is a mantra, but you are allowed to throw in constructor if you can't put the object in a coherent state

Comment: Throwing exceptions in a constructor is not a bad practice. In fact, it is the only reasonable way for a constructor to indicate that there is a problem; e.g. parameters are invalid

Comment: Not the exact wording but...https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/411117/throwing-exception-from-constructor

Comment: With the factory pattern I will delegate the "can't read file" problem into another class. "Always instanziate useable objects" vs. Don't use exception in a constructor. The init method leads to an object which is "half useable" if forgotten to be called...

Answer (score 3):

Good advice:

- Exceptions should not be allowed to escape from a destructor.

This may have morphed into bad advice:

- Don't throw an exception from inside a constructor!

Exceptions are permitted within constructors.  If construction fails, throwing an exception ensures that the object is not constructed, eliminating the possibility of using an object in an invalid state.

Another approach (to avoid) is to move the error prone tasks into an `init()` function and have the constructor do nothing that can fail.  This may lead to use of objects in invalid states and may pollute all methods with checks to ensure `init()` has been called.

Comment: Another possibility may be to wrap the constructor into a factory function, that does all error-prone tasks before and after the constructor. In that way one avoids using an object in invalid state.